# Inserir data escrita na textbox em um certo formato para o banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  conn.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO (StartDate) 
  VALUES(@StartDate)", conn))
  {                                  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", txtStartDate.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Queria que o formato que o usuário escrever na *TextBox* fosse este:

> 2017-09-26 11:24:39.693

Quando escrevo este valor na *textbox* e clico no botão gera esse erro: A conversão de um tipo de dados *nvarchar* em um tipo de dados *datetime* resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.

Como faço para corrigi-lo?

Outra dúvida, como posso fazer um *DateTimePicker* neste formato:

> 2017-09-26 11:24:39.693

E mandar para o banco de dados quando clicar no botão, igual ao código acima?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converta seu texto para um formato *dateTime* desta forma

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null););
```

Para setar um *DateTimePicker* para um [formato](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) especifico, basta utilizar o seguinte código:

```
seuDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

onde o formato que deseja seria "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

ou o formato pode ser alterado diretamente na propriedade CustomFormat do *DateTimePicker*

[image: DateTimePicker Properties]

Comment: O converter deu este erro: não é possível converter de "System.Globalization.CultureInfo" para "System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles Já o DateTimePicker, aonde posso utilizar este código?

Comment: @ViniciusBittencourt tente agora o novo código para converter, e onde editar esta na resposta..mas quanto ao código você poderia inserir no Load por exemplo mas a melhor maneira sera definir nas propriedades mesmo!

Comment: Deu certo, porém queria que tivesse Milisegundos no formato, como ficaria? E como posso selecionar o horário no DataTimePicker ou não tem como?

Comment: @ViniciusBittencourt  este link https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx mostra as possibilidades de formato de data/hora mas em minha maquina não funcionou os milisegundos, e a hora precisa mudar a configuração 'Format' para custom, você poderá escolher a hora no próprio datetimepicker

Comment: Não tem como mudar o horário no DateTimePicker?

Comment: @ViniciusBittencourt tem sim, mas não pela opção do calendário, somente digitando!